# Regex to match symbols starts with symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find symbols that start with **Ã** or **â** using Regex.

```
La SoufriÃ¨re
tailâ€”an
```

So found strings should be.

```
Ã¨
â€”
```

Is it possible and if possible what is the good Regex?

Comment: This is an encoding problem, ANSI `La SoufriÃ¨re` becomes UTF8 `La Soufrière`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match anything that starts with Ã or â and also take along anything that's not alphanumeric an underscore or white space

```
[Ãâ][^\w\s]*
```

Comment: This will match `bjdsfÃâ` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/X1MgKR/1). Precede the expression with `^` or `\b` to make sure the string starts with that character as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/X1MgKR/2)